# How do I authenticate WordPress non-admin users in a flutter app with JWT and flutter_wordpress package?

Tags: wordpress, flutter, jwt, wordpress-rest-api

I am new to Flutter and I am building an app in Flutter for a previously existing WordPress membership site.

Currently I am using the flutter_wordpress 0.1.4 package and the ‘JWT Authentication for WP REST API’ plugin on the WordPress site to try to authenticate users (members).
(https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_wordpress
and https://wordpress.org/plugins/jwt-authentication-for-wp-rest-api/)

The problem is I am getting an error when authenticating non-admin users:

`flutter: Failed to fetch user: WordPress Error! code: wp_empty_list, message: No users found, status: null`

And even when I use an admin account I don’t get a Token or any user information other than name and id.

Here is the flutter code for my login screen:

```
import 'package:flutter_wordpress/flutter_wordpress.dart' as wp;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SignUpScreen extends StatefulWidget {
 static const id = 'sign_up_screen';

 @override
 _SignUpScreenState createState() => _SignUpScreenState();
}

class _SignUpScreenState extends State<SignUpScreen> {
 static final wp.WordPress wordPress = wp.WordPress(
   baseUrl: 'https://example.com',
   authenticator: wp.WordPressAuthenticator.JWT,
   adminName: '',
   adminKey: '',
 );

 void authUser({userName, password}) {
   Future<wp.User> response = wordPress.authenticateUser(
     username: userName,
     password: password,
   );
   response.then((user) {
     print(user);
   }).catchError((err) {
     print('Failed to fetch user: $err');
   });
 }
```

Note that if I use Postman to post a username and password to the `/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token` endpoint the response gives a `token`, `user_email`, `user_nicename`, `user_display_name`, even for a non-admin so it seems to be set up properly on the WordPress site as this is the correct response.

EDIT: Also, I forgot to say that I found this Stack Overflow post that is very related: [Can not authenticate a user who is not an administrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56060812/can-not-authenticate-a-user-who-is-not-an-administrator) 
But the problem is I don't understand what this part meant - "allowing everyone to access /wp-json/wp/v2/users in your server/jwt configuration will fix it."

Answer (score 0):

The error you get :

```
flutter: Failed to fetch user: WordPress Error! code: wp_empty_list, message: No users found, status: null
```

is due to the fact that WordPress API only show lists of users with posts by default and to fix this implement the answer given on the thread here:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/301068/wp-rest-api-only-returning-partial-list-of-users